# Android Fragment issue

Tags: java, android, static, android-fragments

i'm new to Android, (not programming, or even Java) so bear with me.

I'm trying to get a handle on the use of fragments.

I've got a project that I've created using the default swipe/actionbar.  I've extended this further to handle the settings i want.... however i don't quite understand what's going on/how to fix this.

```
/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 8 total pages.
        return 8;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        case 3:
            return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
        case 4:
            return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l);
        case 5:
            return getString(R.string.title_section6).toUpperCase(l);
        case 6:
            return getString(R.string.title_section7).toUpperCase(l);
        case 7:
            return getString(R.string.title_section8).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int position;

        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)-1;
        View rootView;
        TextView dummyTextView;
```

I don't really want anything static or final here, and I've got it mostly worked out but I don't understand the following line or how to fix it.  I kinda get what it's doing.

```
args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
```

The error is: cannot make a static reference to the non-static field DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER

There is probably a simple fix for this, i just am unfamiliar enough with Android and Java, as my current job i spend all my time in SQL Server.

-- EDITED ADDITIONS
i'm not opposed to anything static or final etc.   the problem i'm not quite understanding is when i want to DO something in each of those fragments.  I have a textview on each of those layouts and i want to be able to manipulate them say in a loop.  I think i'm stuck in a circle and can't figure my way out... lol.

For example below the code I put above is

```
    case 4:
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_location,container, false);
            dummyTextView= (TextView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.section_label);

            // location
            Button btnShowLocation = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
            Button btnShowDBLocList = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnShowDBLocList);
            Button btnLocationsCount = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLocationsCount);
            Button btnTruncateDBLocationsTable = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTruncateDBLocationsTable);

            btnTruncateDBLocationsTable.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override                
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
                    int intCount = 0;

                    /*if (activity != null) {
                        //dummyTextView.setText("");
                     try {
                         locationDatabaseHandler.truncateLocationTable();
                         intCount = locationDatabaseHandler.getLocationCount();
                     } catch (Exception e){
                         //dummyTextView.append(e.toString());
                     }
                     //dummyTextView.append("Count:" + intCount + "\n\n");
                     Toast.makeText(activity, "toast_you_just_clicked_a_fragment btnTruncateDBLocationsTable button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }*/
                }
            });

            dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.append("\nLocation Stuff\n");
            break;
```

//dummyTextView.append("Count:" + intCount + "\n\n");

I run into a circle where if I dummyTextView try to use the dummmyText w/in the onClick event, it says that i need to make it static (quick fix) with a complaining error of : cannot refer to a non-final variable dummy7Text inside an indder class defined in a different method.

I've added a variables to handle this inside the onCreate that get filled for (LayoutInflater and Viewgroup, and then reference them w/in the onclick (not shown), but when i go in and instansiate ... nothing happens with the textviews...

There is something i'm not quite getting here, and once i get by that hurdle, i'll have this by the balls, and will be able to make it do what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't really want anything static or final here

Why? They will not negatively impact performance, nor are they a sign of poor coding practices.

> I don't understand the following line

Every Fragment can be created with a Bundle containing any number of key-value pairs. `DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER` is a the key (a String), and `position + 1` is the value. Thus this code is telling the new `DummySectionFragment` which section of content the Fragment should show.

This method is preferable to putting these arguments in a constructor because your custom constructor for a Fragment isn't guaranteed to be called. There are many ways for Android to generate Fragments, so this lowers the possibility of problems such as NullPointerExceptions.

> the error is: cannot make a static reference to the non-static field DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER

As you seem to know, `DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER` is referring to a static field within the `DummySectionFragment` class called `ARG_SECTION_NUMBER`. By making this field non-static, you can no longer reference this constant value without a `DummySectionFragment` instance.

Another option (if you *really* don't want a static field) would be to hardcode the String. Thus your code would be:

```java
args.putInt("section_number", position + 1);
```

However, a public static field is a much better coding practice and will prevent silly mistakes with typos in your Strings.

> I run into a cirle where if i dummyTextView try to use the dummmyText w/in the onClick event, it says that i need to make it static (quick fix) with a complaining error of : cannot refer to a non-final variable dummy7Text inside an indder class defined in a different method.

Instead of using an anonymous inner class, I would let your Fragment implement `OnClickListener`.

For example:

```java
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...

         Button btnTruncateDBLocationsTable = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnTruncateDBLocationsTable);
         btnTruncateDBLocationsTable.setOnClickListener(this);

        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // You can reference dummyTextView here without any problems
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, i'm starting to get a slight handle on what's goin on, please see my edits and additions for further clarification as to what i want to do.   i think i'm close.

Comment: For your additional question about the `OnClickListener`- In this case I would suggest having your Fragment implement `OnClickListener` instead of trying to work with an anonymous inner class. That way you don't need to worry about making your variables static or final so that they are available to the inner class.

Comment: example, would help a LOT?   i've written in Java before, but it's been probably 8 yrs... and i'm digging my way back in, i spend a LOT more time herding databases(DBA) than coding, but darn it I LIKE to code...  
I have putbuttons on each of these fragments to allow for various funcationality that i have implimented in another project, and i'm trying to duplicate the functionality thru a new interface (is why i'm even doing this atm).

Comment: thanks.  trying to make sure i understand correctly.   If i add that, i should be able to get access to my Textview w/in my onclick events for the button?  I do have to say I'm enjoying this site more and more due to the high quality answers i've recieved.  thank you for your help!  if my understanding is correct, then I'll mark this an answer and should be over 15 rep and mark you up.

Comment: Yep, you can access your TextView in the `onClick` function in my example. Just be sure to call `btnTruncateDBLocationsTable.setOnClickListener(this)`!

Comment: ok, i think we're close and I would of moved this to chat but not quite enough rep yet.

where do i set: btnTruncateDBLocationsTable.setOnClickListener(this)?  in the onClick?  this is one of about 15-20 buttons over 8 fragments.   This is all an excercise to take some existing code that works well under a 'blank' interface that i added activities and buttons to those layout, and in trying to recreat functionality get a better understanding of the andriod interfaces.

Comment: I would put it in `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 0):

that means that `ARG_SECTION_NUMBER` should be declared as `public static`. Better if it declared as  `public static final`